# How could I read 4k csv file with phpexcel

Tags: csv, exception, phpexcel

I can read a few csv rows using phpexcel, but when I try to read 4k rows an exception is thrown and I get the following message:

Notice: Undefined index:
Error loading file "": Could not open for reading! File does not exist.

```
$nomOrigine = $_FILES["monfichier"]["name"];
$elementsChemin = pathinfo($nomOrigine);
try {
    $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($nomOrigine);
    $objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
} catch(Exception $e) {
    die(_'Error loading file "'.pathinfo($nomOrigine,PATHINFO_BASENAME).'": '.$e->getMessage()_);
}
```

Comment: Can you share some code? Reading a file with more rows should not trigger this exception... So I guess the path to the file must be wrong

Comment: @Adrien My code works for xls and xslx, it was inactive for csv in the switch case part- IOFactory.php I've actived and it ran perfctly only for 3306 rows . If I add one or more the error displays without any returns data.

Comment: Are you trying to read a file that is being uploaded via a form?

Comment: I mean... It looks like you are. The files that you can't read are probably larger than the (if I remember correctly) `max_upload_size` or `post_max_size` or something like that, which would cause the file to not be received on the server. It's a `php.ini` setting.

Comment: @Jakar exactly and definitly you're right. My post_max_size was in 3M and I`ve changed to 20M, or should I put more Megas?

Comment: @java2dev, see my answer. Let me know if you have any other questions regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

When posting data, if `post_max_size` is smaller than the file (or other data) that is being uploaded, the file will not be received on the server and you may get (as you did) an error that doesn't seem to make sense.

Increase your `post_max_size` to the largest value that you think you will need, but if you need a very large size then you should not be doing file uploads via a form.

I say that because with, for example, a 100MB file, the upload time will be very long, and (last I checked) user feedback is not very good, and if there is an error on client or server, then the upload will have to be restarted completely. You can do research on other upload methods if you think you'll need such sizable uploads.

I imagine 20M (as you mentioned in comment) will be fine, but that's really up to you and what size of files you expect to be dealing with.

Comment: could you give me a specific word or link about the upload methods, because, I used a file with 44k rows and with size 75 M it was very long to display all data using core i5 laptop and 8 GB in RAM, moreover I add memory_size in the php.ini to 2048.

Comment: @java2dev, I'll do some searching in a day or two (or when I get the time) and see if I can find anything useful. But, you might need to use flash... but I'm not sure... You also might want to do some searching for handling large chunks of memory and large strings/files in PHP. I haven't actually dealt with processing large files before, so I'm not sure, but it might be in part due to the performance of `PHPExcel_IOFactory`. Also, do you mean that you have a local PHP server on your laptop or just that you're uploading from the laptop?

Comment: do you think if I try to connect the tool directly to the database can load data from DB and display it as html will be more efficient or not?

Comment: I work with wamp that include apache server, isn't it?